# Storing strings into an array?

Tags: java

I have a java applet text area that I paste strings separated by a comma.

How can I explode a list separated by a comma, as in PHP, and store each string separated by a comma into an array called name[]?

Example list: `Sara,Michael,Sam,Katie,Kyle,Tom,Dan`

`String name[] = {"Sara", "Michael", "Sam", "Katie", "Kyle", "Tom", "Dan"};`

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String[] name = str.split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty basic stuff. Java `String`'s have a built in string-splitting method.

```
String[] name = rawText.split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple using [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), as others mentioned.  Might be a good idea to [trim()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) the results to be safe (e.g. to handle input of `Sara, Michael, Sam, Katie, Kyle, Tom, Dan`)

```
String[] names = input.split(',');
for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    names[i] = names[i].trim();
}
```

Comment: There are simpler ways to do the trimming ... assuming that it is part of the requirement; e.g. `String[] names = input.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");`